# How to Trigger css animation both on scrolling down and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using several CSS animations on a project. My problem is these animations get triggered only once, when scrolling down. I need them to be triggered every time the user scrolls by them, whether going up or down the page.

CSS

```
.slideRight{

    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight; 

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    visibility: visible !important; 

}

@keyframes slideRight {

    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateX(4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateX(-2%);
    }               
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   

}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    65%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
    }
    95%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2%);
    }           
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="animation-test element-to-hide" style="visibility:visible;">Something</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('.animation-test').each(function(){

        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideRight");
        }

    });

});

$('.element-to-hide').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozww5cvj/3/)

Comment: since you're using jquery, have you looked into using jquery's animate instead of native animations? Its got better x-browser support (animation doesn't work in ie9 and b4). you could augment with jquery-ui.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should work.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ozww5cvj/18/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.animation-test').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow) {
            $(this).addClass("slideRight");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("slideRight");
        }
    });
});
```

Basically its just using an if statement to find whether the element is within the view port and adding and removing the class. You can toggle the visibility of the element by using:

```
.element-to-hide{
    visibility:hidden; 
} 
.slideRight {
    visibility: visible;
    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example is fine when scrolling Up, but when scrolling Down the element is visible when the animation is triggered. The point is to have the elements come into the page through animation. Would it be possible to make it invisible until the animation is triggered?

Comment: Hi Paul, I appreciate your help. For some reason it seams to work fine on your fiddle but not on my site. Please take a look [**HERE**](http://davidmartins.pt/test/w.htm)

Comment: Paul, first of all thank you for your time and effort. I see the same thing in all latest versions of Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Basically, the animated element, in this case the butterfly graphics you see on my page, are just there, perfectly visible as you scroll down, and then they disappear and the animation kicks in.

Comment: @DavidMartins Ah, sorry... You need to remove the inline `visibility: visible;`

Comment: @DavidMartins `<div class="content animation-test element-to-hide slideRight" style="visibility:visible;">`

Comment: @apaul I think I already called the correct class but still nothing happen. The animation class is not triggered. May I know why? https://codepen.io/nazrinnoorzan/pen/XyeeMo

Comment: For me this formula works pretty better (new variable `var windowHeight = $(window).height();`): `imagePos + imageHeight < topOfWindow + windowHeight && imagePos > topOfWindow`